# HTML form action with php

Tags: php, html, forms

```
<form id="cat_insert" method="POST" action="admin-process.php?action=cat_insert" onsubmit="return false;">
```

I found this format of HTML form in the sample code provided by my teacher. I know apply php code after submitting the form would use `action="admin-process.php"`. But I don't understanding what is "?" after the php in this case, and the meaning of on submit.

Comment: ? tells that your parameters start after this

Comment: and parameters passed here will be available in `$_GET['paramname']`. In this case as `$_GET['action']` with value 'cat_insert'. This way you can pass POST and GET Parameters at the same time when submitting a form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`?` at the end of `admin-process.php?action=cat_insert` denotes where the url parameters begin. This allows you to pass information from one page to the next using the `GET` method. This is in addition to the parameters passed through to `admin-process.php` by the form which use the `POST` method.

The `GET` method is useful for passing a reasonable amount of non sensitive data between pages, while the `POST` method has less limitations and is best for more sensitive data.

In this instance you could obtain the value of `action` on `admin-process.php` by using either `$_GET['action']` or `$_REQUEST['action']` (`$_REQUEST` includes the contents of `$_GET`, `$_POST` and `$_COOKIE`).

`onsubmit="return false;"` is JavaScript and is used to suppress the default behaviour of the form when it is submitted, this will stop the form from submitting (if JavaScript is enabled). This is likely because some other action is taken by JavaScript (for example validation), exactly what this is for in this case is unclear given the snippet of code.